# Cannot run program catalina.sh: error=13, Permission denied

Tags: linux, tomcat

> Cannot run program "/home/diyerbek/IdeaProjects/apache-tomcat-9.0.71 (2)/apache-tomcat-9.0.71/bin/catalina.sh" (in directory "/home/diyerbek/IdeaProjects/apache-tomcat-9.0.71 (2)/apache-tomcat-9.0.71/bin"): error=13, Permission denied

I don't know what I did wrong when I run Tomcat.
i am using ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Please provide details on how you are running tomcat, from some ide or using command line, also share screenshots and stack trace.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Change the rules like this:

```
user@user:~/apache-tomcat-9.0.71/bin$ chmod +x catalina.sh
```